# OraOLEDB.Oracle not showing up in Providers in Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, oracle-12c, oledb

Im trying to link the Oracle database to our SQL Server database. However `OraOLEDB.Oracle` is not in the Providers list on the Linked Servers. I have installed **Oracle Database Client (12.1.0.2.0) for Microsoft Windows(x86)** from the [Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/database12c-win64-download-2297732.html), did a tnsping from the Oracle server that I am going to link to SQL Server, and setup my `tnsname.ora` file like this

```
 hx0014.ourserver.com =
   (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 139.180.174.214)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME =) 
    )
  )
```

I restarted our SQL Server server afterwards, but `OraOLEDB.Oracle` still doesn't show up.

Can anyone guide me as to what's wrong?

Comment: You installed the 32-bit driver, are you using 32-bit SQL Server?

Comment: @SeanGallardy we are using 64bit. From what I've read it doesnt matter if your platform is x64. What matters is the app running it. Correct me if im wrong

Comment: You do require 64 bit installation. Once you do that provider will show up in linked server provider list.

Comment: AFAIK you will need the 64-bit one and not the 32-bit one: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2013/10/02/creating-a-linked-server-for-oracle-in-64bit-sql-server/